How do I create hidden fields in Django 4/5?
I am using this simple example just for discussion:
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(...)        # stored in table
    last_name = models.CharField(...)         # stored in table
    full_name = first_name + ' ' + last_name  # not stored in table

I want only full_name to be accessible to be created, saved, retrieved. It is a combination of first_name and last_name. When the full_name needs to be saved, it will be split by spaces, and first split goes to first_name and rest goes to last_name. I don't want first_name and last_name to be directly accessible from forms or even Django commands that may directly use User instantantiation, ModelModel manager create or User save methods.
Do I have to hack into the Metaclass (like here: https://github.com/vitaly-efremov/django-private-field/blob/master/private_field_meta.py, 7 years old code), or is there something simpler in Django 4/5?

This was just a pedantic question, I am exploring Django right now. I am beginning to think it may introduce lot of complications if I want to make a fields as fake that depends on fields that are real columns that are never directly accessible. If its a fake field, technically I should be able to use it other relations, even as unique columns. Does this sound like a bad idea?

I believe you are talking about @property decorator.
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(...)        # stored in table
    last_name = models.CharField(...)         # stored in table

    @property
    def full_name(self):                      # not stored in table
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

you can call it using user_obj.full_name

A @property is not sufficient. When saving to the model, only Model.full_name should be accessible, and it should store to underlying 2 separate columns. Also, I should be able to write a query that full_name contains something.

Hi, @fishfin, can you please add this in your question. also when you access the instances of an Model you get all it's fields and property using . for writing query you can use query expression like Q and F: ref

Looks like Generated Field is the partial answer (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#generatedfield). Hiding a field still remains unresolved.

For the generated fields, Django 5 has catered for it.
For more details check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/#database-generated-model-field
Instead of:
full_name = **first_name + ' ' + last_name**

You can do it this way:
full_name = models.GeneratedField(
            expression=Func(F("first_name"), F("last_name"), function="CONCAT", output_field=CharField()),
            output_field=models.CharField(),
            db_persist=True,
          )


Doesn't this create the equivalent of FirstLast instead of First Last?

Also if you're now aware Django does have a Concat class for that particular database function.
